# Mongoose - How to Chain Save So Data Can Be Saved to Multiple Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I have read all sorts of variations of this on stackoverflow but I cannot seem to find a post that exactly explains what I'm trying to achieve, at the same time I believe this has to be a very common task during saving data.
So I need to save data to one collection and then read the _id from that doc and save it to a doc in a different collection. I have the following code and I can see the correct data with console.log but I don't see the data being saved to the database.
Appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thank you!

```
router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, name, country } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = new User({ email, password });

    await user.save((error, doc) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        const userProfile = new UserProfile({  userId: doc._id, name, country });
        userProfile.save((error, doc) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error)
          } else {
            console.log(doc) // Can see this log with the correct data
          }
        });
      }
    });
    const token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id}, 'MY_KEY');
    res.send({ token });
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(422).send(error.message)
  }
})
```

Comment: I believe you are missing `await` in `userProfile.save((error, doc) => {...`, but it shouldn't make a big difference. Could you query and print all users before `user.save` and after `user.save`? And user profiles, if possible?

Comment: You will not believe this. Don't think this is a code issue. Today I woke up and I had been logged out of the Mongo Manager. I logged back in and the new collections was there with all records from yesterday. I have no clue why would that happen. userProfile was a brand new collection whereas user was already there so not sure what I needed to do. I do remember reloading the page in the browser. Anyone has any thoughts about this, please let me know. So for now this is working :-)